# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libopencv_java247 in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

In oder to create a simple opencv java project I folled this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) step by step but

when I run the associated exemple I get the folowwing error :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libopencv_java247 in java.library.path`

**EDIT**

I read all similar questions and I try those solutions

--

`-Djava.library.path=/home/noura/Desktop/opencv/build/lib/`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/noura/Desktop/opencv/build/lib`

but the problem is not solved

Comment: any response please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just I should write

`System.loadLibrary("opencv_java247");`

instead of

`System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java247");`